# Conditional Copying Of Rows Google Spreedsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a workbook with 13 sheets 1 for each month and a blank one. Everyone of the worksheets is formatted the same. I'm wanting to copy every row that has the word "Overdue" in the same column to the last sheet to give a master list of all over due inspections. I have read 3 posts about similar issues but I cannot grasp what each line of code does well enough to mold it for what I need. I'm willing to tip someone via paypal if they will help me implement this solution. I'm a diesel mechanic not a programmer lol, my boss just thinks I can do anything.

The word Overdue will always be in Row 'I' of all 12 worksheets(1 for each month)

I can share the document as well if that helps.

Comment: SO is a place where programmers help each other on specific issues for free. So, if you've tried something and need specific help, the community here will try its best to help. However, if you need a readymade solution, then SO is not the best place

Answer (score 0):

It may look some thing like this...

```
function moveRows() {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A2:I').getValues();
  var row, len, data = [];

  for (row = 0, len = values.length; row < len; row++)
    if (values[row][8] == 'Overdue') 
      data.push([values[row]]);

  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR_SS_ID').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = dest.getLastRow();
  dest.getRange('A1').offset(lastRow, 0, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

It's not removing any rows from the source sheet (just 1 sheet not 13 like you need it setup for), just copying them.

Comment: So if I needed to edit this to copy from all 12 sheets I would need to put ".getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('A2:I').getValues();
  var row, len, data = [];" into a loop right

Comment: You don't want `data` to be reset in the loop, but `Sheet1` will need to be replaced each loop iteration.  Include the existing `for loop` in the new one too.